# How to add actual price in x label?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new in python. I'm trying to build plot actual vs predicted price, but don't know how to do it. 
I need actual price in 'x' and predicted in 'y'.

```py
Code
df_pred.plot(y='SalePrice',x='Id')
df_tr.plot(y='SalePrice',x='Id')
##plt.scatter(X_train[:,0], y_train, color = 'red')
##plt.plot(X_test, regressor.predict(X_test), color = 'green')
plt.title('predicted vs actual price ')
plt.xlabel('id')
plt.ylabel('price')
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a single figure, you can put the two plots in the same figure as following

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df_pred.plot(y='SalePrice',x='Id', ax=ax)
df_tr.plot(y='SalePrice',x='Id', ax=ax)
```

If you want to just plot the `SalePrice` from the two dataframes, you can do the following scatter plot

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df_tr['SalePrice'], df_pred['SalePrice'])
```